# Unable to fetch data from form to function

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have two fields in form and onsubmit() event I am calling function. When I click udpate button I could not get the values of "sent", all other values fetched correctly.

In case of insert button, sent is fetched correctly.

I am tracking the values using aler button. Can it be done using firebug too?

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function showUser(form, e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.returnValue=false;
        var xmlhttp;
        var submit = form.getElementsByClassName('submit')[0];
        var sent = document.getElementsByName('sent')[0].value || '';
        var id = document.getElementsByName('id')[0].value || '';

        **alert(id);
        alert(sent);
    alert(submit.name);
    alert(submit.value);**

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open(form.method, form.action, true);
        xmlhttp.send('sent=' + sent + '&id=' + id + '&' + submit.name + '=' + submit.value);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="ajax_test.php" method="POST" onsubmit="showUser(this, event)">
        <label>Enter the sentence: <input type="text" name="sent"></label><br />
        <input type="submit" class="submit" name="insert" value="submit"  />
    </form>

    <h4>UPDATE</h4>
    <form action="ajax_test.php" method="POST" onsubmit="showUser(this, event)">
        <pre>
            <label>Enter the ID:</label><input type="text" name="id"><br>
            <label>Enter the sentence:<input type="text" name="sent"></label><br />
        </pre>
        <input type="submit" class="submit" value="submit" name="update"/>
    </form>

    <br />
    <div id="txtHint">
        <b>Person info will be listed here.</b>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the form ID and NAME?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're always getting the first `sent` and `id` elements because you're using `document.getElementsByName`, so you need to grab the ones within the form that is submitted. By always getting the first, you will get the values from the insert form even when the update form is submitted.

```
var sent = form.elements['sent'].value;
var id = form.elements['id'].value;
```

The above will get the `sent` and `id` values from the form that was submitted, based on the form object that was passed as an argument.

Comment: he can also use different ID instead

Comment: Could do but OP is trying to reuse the same code to handle both forms, so by setting all of the inputs unique IDs, the code would get messy by having to determine which form is submitted, then have a switch to get the element by ID.

Comment: It need to be documents.elements[];

Answer (score -1):

You can use console.log(...) and console.debug() with firebug.
See the documentation for more info: https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API

Not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but you should at least provide us with a copy of ajax_test.php if you want us to test your code. Do you get any error messages in to firebug console?

Also, why not use the ajax features of jQuery? That would make things far easier on yourself. Piao Yishi has a good tutorial on NetTuts+ on how to do that: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/
Doing so might just solve your problems.

Comment: Why is this answer down voted? The OP has asked exactly 1 question and I gave the answer.